# Não estou a conseguir identificar o erro no meu script

Tags: bash

```
if [  $#  -eq  1  ]
    then$atletas=$(find  treinos  -maxdepth  1  -mindepth  1  -type  d)
    for  a  in  $atletas
    do
      dados=$(find  $a  -mindepth  1  -maxdepth  1  -type  f  -name  "????-??-??.txt")
      nome=$(echo  $a  |  cut  -f2  -d  "/")
      for  d  in  $dados
      do
        minutos=$(cat  $d  |  grep  "^$1"  |  cut  -f2  -d  ":")
        dia=$(echo  $d  |  cut  -f3  -d  "-"  |  cut  -f1  -d  ".")
        ficheiro="treinos/${1}_${nome}.csv"
        treino="$dia;$minutos"
        echo  $treino  >>  $ficheiro
      done
    done
    else
    echo  "Deve  inserir  exatamente  um  parâmetro!"

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu script está:

```
then$atletas=$(find
```

Mas o correto é:

```
then $atletas=$(find
```